# Toolbar not hiding on RecyclerView scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I'm trying to make the `Toolbar` in my app hide and show based on the `RecyclerView`'s scrolling. This gif shows what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: GIF]

I'm following [this tutorial](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/) and not getting the results I'm looking for. Here is my activity's layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> And here's the `Toolbar` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

When I run this code, the `Toolbar` completely disappears. What's wrong?

Comment: take a look at this https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part2%29/

Comment: I'd like to follow the Part 3 tutorial because I'm going to implement a FAB soon. @SanketKachhela

Comment: Same here. I have almost the same structure in my app and followed the same tutorial but toolbar won't hide on scroll. I'll let you know if i manage to work this out

Comment: I have the same issue. Anyone solved it?

Comment: @bashan I managed to solve this and move onto another problem in a separate thread, but I can't remember how since this was a while ago. It might help though, check it out http://stackoverflow.com/a/31241616/3038563

Answer (score 2):

If your `RecyclerView` is inside of a fragment try putting the following code in the root view of the fragment layout: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. The view that contains that must be a direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

As @orrett3 described just add this line

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to your container `FrameLayout` like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

I assumed the `RecyclerView` is a child of this container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 actions:

1. remove from toolbar xml this line:

   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
2. As other answers, add this line to layout that wrap your fragment's
   (in your case it's frame layout)

   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"