# Toolbar leaving white space with hide on RecyclerView scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to hide my Toolbar on the RecyclerView scroll and so far it seems to have hidden, but it's leaving a white blank with it. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the overlay of my MainActivity's layout and the fragment in the FrameLayout.

[image: why is this happening to me ._.]

Here is my `activity_main.xml`. I need the FrameLayout because I am loading different fragments with selection of an item in the Navigation Drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is the code in the fragment that contains the RecyclerView.

```
...
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle("Unit One");

        rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();

        rv.addOnScrollListener(showHideToolbarListener = new RecyclerViewUtils.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener(MainActivity.toolbar));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            showHideToolbarListener.onRestoreInstanceState((RecyclerViewUtils.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener.State) savedInstanceState
                    .getParcelable(RecyclerViewUtils.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener.SHOW_HIDE_TOOLBAR_LISTENER_STATE));
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(RecyclerViewUtils.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener.SHOW_HIDE_TOOLBAR_LISTENER_STATE,
                showHideToolbarListener.onSaveInstanceState());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

And lastly, the RecyclerView layout in `fragment_main.xml`:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rv" />
```

This is a follow up to my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218254/toolbar-not-hiding-on-recyclerview-scroll), but I wanted to ask a new question since I'm trying a [different method](http://rylexr.tinbytes.com/2015/04/27/how-to-hideshow-android-toolbar-when-scrolling-google-play-musics-behavior/) this time (don't read the entire post, see the edit at the bottom). Here is his [MainActivity](https://github.com/rylexr/android-show-hide-toolbar/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tinbytes/samples/showhidetoolbar/MainActivity2.java) and the actual [scrolling listener code](https://github.com/rylexr/android-show-hide-toolbar/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tinbytes/samples/showhidetoolbar/util/RecyclerViewUtils.java).

I apologize if this seems like me saying "here's my shit go fix it" but I've spent almost two hours searching for a possible solution to this. **As always, I appreciate the help greatly.**

Comment: post you item layout of `RecyclerView`. Did you use `CardView`? You item has elevation effect or edge shadow effect...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that translateY, which you're using to animate the toolbar, only shifts what's drawn on the screen and not the view location itself. That means that the view holding the toolbar still occupies that space at the top in the linear layout.

Use the same layout he's using in his [main_activity.xml](https://github.com/rylexr/android-show-hide-toolbar/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml).
You can also use a FrameLayout. The important thing is that you put the toolbar on top of the RecyclerView (below in the xml) and add a top padding to the RecyclerView equal to the toolbar height.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  ..... />
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer because it's the most correct for anyone else who stumbles upon this question. I changed my LinearLayout to a FrameLayout and placed the Toolbar below the child FrameLayout (which is used for the fragment). Additional credits: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3ca6gt/stackoverflow_question_problems_with_toolbar/cstn8t6

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use the new [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and its `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

For more example, you can get inspired by Chris Banes' demo application [CheeseSquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/) or by [this tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/quick-return-pattern-with-android-design-support-library/).

Comment: This approach did not work for me as my DrawerLayout is the root element in my main_activity.xml

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial telling you how to do it using RecyclerView. https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

However, this also tells you to add paddingTop = actionBarSize in the layout. I didnt really like that approach but I solved it that way for now.