# Toolbar leaving space when I tried to hide on RecyclerView scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to hide my `toolbar` on the scroll of `recyclerView`. And it hides on the scroll but the **problem** is that **it leaves blank space after hiding**.

And I follow the links below -

1 - [TutLinks 1](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/)

2 - [TutLinks 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241207/toolbar-leaving-white-space-with-hide-on-recyclerview-scroll)

Comment: Can you please post your app them from style.xml?

Comment: the coordinatorlayout takes care of hiding the toolbar with the scrolling. Why are you making it manually ?\

Comment: @Blackbelt actually i have tried with collapsable toolbar but it was not working fine, so I tried to do this manually. Can u plz share the tutorial how to do it by simply coordinatorlayout.

Comment: what do you mean by *but it was not working fine* ?

Comment: actually, I want on the scrolling, the toolbar is hidden and my custom layout be my new toolbar on the top and the problem was, it collapse the my custom layout as a toolbar and never show the default toolbar.

Comment: @Blackbelt it was more complex. So I want to fix by manually, and getting the above problem.

Comment: So you want a custom layout to set as your toolbar? I'm not very clear about your question now.

Comment: @ReazMurshed please see edit. I have posted the style.xml file.

Comment: @ReazMurshed and I will look into the issue mentioned in cmt, but before that please answer or explain me the issues "why my toolbar leaves the blank space".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem and fixed it. Actually, the problem is in **include tag**.

In above code, I had used include tag and **include tag can't perform the functionality of the toolbar**. Means

> app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

does not work in include tag.

If I use the toolbar directly in the XML file with **scrollFlags** then everything works fine.

Or in toolbar.xml add the **layout_scrollFlags**

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"   
    />
```

After changing it, I have not needed to hide and show the toolbar manually.

and Everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

If you want to show it again you call:

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

http://rylexr.tinbytes.com/2015/04/27/how-to-hideshow-android-toolbar-when-scrolling-google-play-musics-behavior/